# Replacing two convoluted for loops with vectorization

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, vectorization

this is my first question, so if I'm doing something wrong, please let me know.

I have two convoluted for loops which work, but are far too slowly. I understand that I should use vectorization to speed things up, but I do not understand how to do it in my example. Any help would be highly appreciated.
The background of my question is that I need to calculate the sum of squared differences (SSD) for daily price data of different stocks for one year. I need to compute this SSD for every possible combination of two stocks out of a list of 1046 stocks, which are saved in a pandas dataframe (with their price data).

So far I have the two for loops that only compute the SSD for every possible combination of the first stock in the list and every other stock. At the moment, I would be happy to just vectorize this two loops, in order to make them a lot faster. I already tried to use while loops or define them in a function but that did not increase the speed as much as I need. If there is still a better way than vectorization, please let me know that I am on the wrong path.

My dataframe "formation_period_1_1991", where I pull the price data from looks basically like this (where "PERMNO" is an identifier for a single stock):

```
data = [['99000', 10], ['99000', 11], ['99000', 12],['98000', 3], ['98000', 2], ['98000', 5],['97000', 9], ['97000',11], ['97000', 10]]
formation_period_1_1991 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['PERMNO', 'Price'])
```

Then I defined a Matrix to save the calculated values for the SSD's:

```
Axis_for_SSD_Matrix = formation_period_1_1991["PERMNO"].unique().tolist()
SSD_Matrix = pd.DataFrame(index=np.arange(formation_period_1_1991["PERMNO"].nunique()), columns=np.arange(formation_period_1_1991["PERMNO"].nunique()))
SSD_Matrix.set_axis(Axis_for_SSD_Matrix, axis="index",inplace=True)
SSD_Matrix.set_axis(Axis_for_SSD_Matrix, axis="columns",inplace=True)
```

In the end, I calculate the SSD's for the first row of my SSD_Matrix with the two for loops:

```
x=3# is equal to number of trading days
no_of_considered_shares =(formation_period_1_1991["PERMNO"].nunique())
j=1

for j in range(1,no_of_considered_shares):
    SSD_calc = 0
    i=0
    for i in range(0,x): #x is no_of_trading_days
        SSD_calc = SSD_calc + (formation_period_1_1991.iloc[i]["Price"]-formation_period_1_1991.iloc[i+x*j]["Price"])**2 
    SSD_Matrix.loc[formation_period_1_1991.iloc[0]["PERMNO"],formation_period_1_1991.iloc[x*j]["PERMNO"]]=SSD_calc
```

The SSD_Matrix looks like this after I run the code:

```
    index 99000 98000 97000
  0  99000  nan   179    5
  1  98000  nan   nan   nan
  2  97000  nan   nan   nan
```

So far it works just as I want, but since my real dataframe "formation_period_1_1991" has 1046 stocks with 253 trading days each, I would be very glad if someone could provide any help on how to vastly increase the speed of this two for loops (I guess by vectorization).
Many thanks!

Comment: "vectorization" means rewriting the code so it uses the faster compiled `numpy` methods (or `pandas` where available).

Comment: Thank you, do you have any idea how I could use those methods here? The numpy commands I found so far don't appear to be helpful here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it is:

```
formation_period_1_1991.index = formation_period_1_1991.index % formation_period_1_1991['PERMNO'].unique().shape[0]
df = formation_period_1_1991.pivot(columns='PERMNO', values='Price')
arr = df.to_numpy()

def combinations(arr):
    n = arr.shape[0]
    upper = np.tri(n,n,-1,dtype='bool').T
    a,b = np.meshgrid(arr,arr)
    return b[upper].reshape(-1), a[upper].reshape(-1)

n = arr.shape[1]
a,b = combinations(np.arange(n))

out = np.zeros((n,n))
out[a,b] = ((arr[:,a]-arr[:,b])**2).sum(axis=0)
out[b,a] = out[a,b]
out_df = pd.DataFrame(out)
out_df.columns = df.columns
out_df.index = df.columns.values
out_df
```

Giving me:

```
PERMNO  97000  98000  99000
97000     0.0  142.0    5.0
98000   142.0    0.0  179.0
99000     5.0  179.0    0.0
```

Notice that I am actually only calculating the upper triangle of your matrix. I just assume that the lower triangle will look like the upper one and that we always will have zeros on the diagonal.

Comment: Without actually looking at it myself I have two guesses. 1: having an example with 3 stocks and 3 prices was a bad idea leading to me taking the number of stocks where I should have taken the number of prices or the other way around. And 2: your index works slightly differently and my way of getting it from long to wide form does not work in your case. I suggest you post a slightly bigger example or one that resembles your data better and I adopt my code.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, I was already able to solve it. You are right, it was about my index, which did not function the same way when it was applied to your function. Now everything seems to work exactly as I need it to. So thank you so much, you cannot imagine how much you helped me!

Comment: @GC2023 I am glad to hear that. You're welcome :).